# Spring JMS json message converter

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms, spring-jms

I have some problems to convert messages from **RabbitMQ** using **spring-jms** module. Previously I send my messages using Rest API endpoint, this endpoint send the message to RabbitMQ queue and process it using *@JmsListener* methods.

Internally this behaviour add a field to determine the Java type, managed by Spring libraries. However now I want to avoid the Rest API call because it's not necessary and I can send the message directly to RabbitMQ.

The problem is when spring try to convert JMS message for *@JmsListener* parameter. I didn't set the type on the message because the sender doesn't need that information but now I cannot convert it directly because *MappingJackson2MessageConverter* want a property for that.

How can I avoid this problem? I want to be able to process all message without needs to know the type in all the "senders".

Message converter bean:

```
   @Bean
   public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
      MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
      converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
      converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
      return converter;
   }
```

Listener sample code:

```
 @JmsListener(concurrency = "listener.concurrency", destination = "queue.name", containerFactory = "container.factory")
 public void processFile(MyDtoClass dto) {
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the converter and override `getJavaTypeForMessage()` to return the type you want...

```
/**
 * Determine a Jackson JavaType for the given JMS Message,
 * typically parsing a type id message property.
 * <p>The default implementation parses the configured type id property name
 * and consults the configured type id mapping. This can be overridden with
 * a different strategy, e.g. doing some heuristics based on message origin.
 * @param message the JMS Message to set the type id on
 * @throws JMSException if thrown by JMS methods
 * @see #setTypeIdOnMessage(Object, javax.jms.Message)
 * @see #setTypeIdPropertyName(String)
 * @see #setTypeIdMappings(java.util.Map)
 */
protected JavaType getJavaTypeForMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
```

Comment: The message is just a json string without any reference to java type or anything to determine the type in the converter, How you can determine the java type here? This is a bit strange for me because the Java type should be determined by the parameter of the method with @JmsListener annotation.

Comment: The `@JmsListener` doesn't have any built-in infrastructure to do that. You could probably do it with a custom `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` with a custom `PayloadArgumentResolver` (docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated-method-signature)).

Comment: Thank you! I will check that option.